# Fail to handle light boxes through selenium java webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, lightbox

I have a problem. When I click on add button, a light box appears and I need to

1. Select it or switch focus on it.
2. Enter name and description in text boxes.

I tried with below code but not succeeded:

```
d1.switchTo().frame(d1.findElement(By.xpath("locator string of text box Name ")));
```

Comment: Hi Aminul - are you sure you need the `switchTo()` at all? Most lightbox implementations do not use frames. If you post your html, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Firebug to find out what attributes you can call on the lightbox other than xpath?